# CSS Color property doesn't apply on .active (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: html, css

I built a very simple navigation bar in `bootstrap 4`. My objective is to style the `font-color` of the .`active class` to black in order to display on which page the user is currently .

Strangely the `.active` class applies to properties such as `font-weight, border, background or text-decoration` but NOT `color`.

Here is a pen:

```
<p data-height="265" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="pVOoXr" data-default-tab="html,result" data-user="fdhu" data-embed-version="2" data-pen-title="color-property-issue" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/fdhu/pen/pVOoXr/">color-property-issue</a> by ferdinand huber (<a href="https://codepen.io/fdhu">@fdhu</a>) on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
<script async src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

Can anybody give me a hint on how to solve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>color property issue</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>

.active {
  font-weight: bold; /*applies*/
  border: 2px solid red; /*applies*/
  background: yellow; /*applies*/
  text-decoration: underline; /*applies*/

  color: black; /*doesn't apply, neither by adding !important*/
 }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand">      
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <div class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link-1</a>
    </div>
   <div class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link-2</a>
    </div> 
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *default* color of the **link** is overriding the **inherited** color of the div.

You need to make the selector more specific so that it applies to the link itself.

```css
.active a {
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: yellow;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand">
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <div class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link-1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link-2</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give the color to `<a>` anchor tag. Because hyperlinks take the default color and also overrides the parent `.active`

```
.active a {    
  color: black;
 }
```

Comment: P.S. I was also wondering why this only happens with 'color' and not with 'underline' which is set on <a> by default, too. I guess the reason for this is that the code is built on Bootstrap. Bootstrap's reboot.css eliminates the underline for <a> by default.

Comment: Yes bootstrap eliminates the underlines for `<a>` tags :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `.active a` class in your `css`

```css
.active {
   font-weight: bold; /*applies*/
   border: 2px solid red; /*applies*/
   background: yellow; /*applies*/
   text-decoration: underline; /*applies*/
   color: black; /*doesn't apply, neither by adding !important*/
 }
     
.active a {
   color: #000;
 }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand">      
  <div class="navbar-nav">
    <div class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link-1</a>
    </div>
   <div class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link-2</a>
    </div> 
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

just give you property`color:#000!important;`important property give the class active to your anchor tag.